# Are the Neo4j SSL files snakeoil.cert and snakeoil.key PEM files?

Tags: rest, ssl, https, config, neo4j

I was trying to connect to the Neo4j HTTPS server through a the [`neo4j-rest-client`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4jrestclient/) using the `snakeoil.key` and `snakeoil.cert` files generated after installing Neo4j from debian sources. However, it seems like those files are not [PEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) formatted, and behind scenes, [`neo4j-rest-client`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4jrestclient/) is only able to handle PEM formatted files because of [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). So, then I created my own `ssl.crt` and `ssl.key` PEM files, but this time looks like Neo4j doesn't like this format. Am I right? Is there any way to have Neo4j Server running in SSL mode with PEM files?

AFAIK, a PEM file should look like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blahblahblah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not PEM files, but you can create a PEM file from the certificate file (snakeoil.crt). See here for instructions:

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

Comment: I already did that, but now I have PEM files in client side and certificate files in Neo4j server side. and, maybe because of this, getting the `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error`. There is no way to have Neo4j running with plain PEM files? It fails when starting. Any chance of adding `ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"` in Tomcat?